# WPF: How to implement a generic window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I'd like to have a reusable window in my desktop application that could potentially have different xamls "injected" into it. Because I'd like all my windows to have the same look (I have a nifty title bar and close button, etc)

For example, I'd like to have a messagebox (ok/cancel/string) used in it. I'd like it to be used to host a form, etc.

I currently have:
MyWindow.xaml/cs (is a Window)
MyMessageBox.xaml/cs (is a User Control)
MyForm.xaml/cs (is a User Control)

So what is the best way to implement this. Do I just put a ContentPresenter in MyWindow and then somehow "inject" the other xamls into it? Do I need the other controls to inherit something from the base window?

I'm just looking for some feedback on the best way to go about what I'm trying to do. Thanks

Comment: I ended up getting some tips and tricks from this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CustomFrames.aspx it was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jamescrisp.org/2008/05/26/wpf-control-inheritance-with-generics/

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be a Window with a Frame, and then load pages into that Frame on demand.

Comment: If you want to implement this (the Form?) as a template then maybe replace Frame by ContentPresenter. But I wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with with [Henk Holterman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961314/wpf-how-to-implement-a-generic-window/4961362#4961362).  I've just written a small 'framework' for WPF applications of this sort.  I use an inteface on the 'content' pages to define common functionality for the code-behind; I have a generic page template that I use to give me a caption block, close button, etc.

I'd avoid visual inheritance with WPF unless you absolutely need it - it can be rather tricky to get right.

Comment: Do you have that framework posted somewhere? or can you explain a bit more detail on how you did this.

Comment: looks like you already found what you needed, but here's the meat of my code:  [link](http://codepaste.net/hz4x3r)

Comment: thanks for posting that code. but i was looking for more of a xaml based approach i.e., <mywindow>..blabla..</mywindow> inside the user controls. i think your code needs you to call methods directly

Answer (score 0):

You should seriously consider using [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) (developed by Microsoft, coming out of the [Patterns & Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices) group) for this; it was built to handle exactly these scenarios, providing tools for [composing UIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921174%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx).

Comment: I'd rather not use that beast of a library for something so simple

Comment: @foreyez: Fair enough, but let's look at what you have - you want to inject and compose UI instances.  That's *exactly* what Prism does.  And consider more complex scenarios you might come across in the future; you will just end up writing more and more code to do something that's already been developed.